# numpy array - unravel_index of argmax v. argmax of sum

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to marginalize an array along one axis and checking that the 1-D peak occurs at the same relevant index as at that of the original 2-D peak. Under what circumstances (form of `x`) should the following assertion fail?

```
def check(x,axis=None):
    import numpy
    m = numpy.sum(x, axis=axis)
    v,w = numpy.unravel_index(numpy.argmax(x), x.shape)
    assert(v==numpy.argmax(m))
    return
```

For `x=numpy.array(range(15)).reshape(5,3)`, `check(x,axis=0)` raises the error, but `check(x,axis=1)` does not. I can't see why an `AssertionError` is ever raised - am I being stupid?

Comment: Did you try printing out the value of 'v' and numpy.argmax(m)? Maybe the actual values will give you a clue

Comment: Does the assertion fail when axis=None? It's probably because the sum function adds up all the values in the array, giving you a single value for m [not an array]. The argmax of this would be always 0

Answer (score 1):

You're checking the wrong coordinate of the unraveled index.  Instead of

```
v,w=numpy.unravel_index(numpy.argmax(x),x.shape)
assert(v==numpy.argmax(m))
```

you probably want

```
vw = numpy.unravel_index(numpy.argmax(x),x.shape)
assert vw[1 - axis] == numpy.argmax(m)
```

or perhaps

```
v,w=numpy.unravel_index(numpy.argmax(x),x.shape)
assert (v if axis == 1 else w) == numpy.argmax(m)
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of your `axis` argument is critical.

With `x` a `(N, M)` array, `m=np.sum(x, axis=axis)` will give you

- a scalar if `axis=None`;
- a `M` array if `axis=0`;
- a `N` array if `axis=1`.

Therefore, your `np.argmax(m)` will always 0 be if `axis=None`, or an integer between `0` and `M` (resp. `N`) if `axis=0` (resp. `axis=1`).

However, your `(v, w) = np.unravel_index(...)` will always give you `v` as an integer between 0 and `N`.

As you can see, with `axis=0`, the range of potential values for `m` is not the same as for `v`, whereas it is for `axis=1`.

So, compare `m` with `v` if `axis=1`, or with `w` if `axis=0` (@ecatmur's answer shows you how).